# Insert row when Cell Value is Greater

Tags: excel, vba, loops, format, range

[Here is my Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RM3E.png) in which i wrote this code

```
     Sub L()
        Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
        Set rng = Range("P12:P1322")
        For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value > 12 Then
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        ActiveCell.Range(rng).Activate
        Copy.selection
        Range(rng).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove
       'Range(rng).Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        End If
        
        Next cell
        End Sub
```

I tried another code too but it was not working.
You see the red cells These cells value is greater than 12 I want to add the row with same formatting below the active row.

Comment: If you're inserting rows, you need to loop from the bottom up.

Comment: Can you please explain in word what you want the code to do. The code is not adding any rows anywhere. Also do you actually have a range called `"rng"` in your sheet? Do you mean `ActiveSheet.Range("rng").Activate` instead of `ActiveCell...`? Why are you activating this range? It doesn't seem to be doing anything other than making you code run that much slower.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry See i want to loop within a range to check if the cell value is greater than 12 if it is true then add the rows below the active range of the same formating as above before I tried with the active cell it just shifted only the cell not row.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you want

```
Sub L()
    Dim i As Long
    With Range("P12:P1322")
        For i = .Rows.Count To 12 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value > 12 Then
                .Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                .Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

The following is significantly faster

```
Sub LImproved()
    Dim dStart As Double
    dStart = Timer
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lCol As Long: lCol = 16 ' column P
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim sRows As String
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lCol).End(xlUp).Row
        'lLastRow = 1322
    
        For i = lLastRow To 12 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, lCol).Value > 12 Then
                sRows = sRows & i + 1 & ":" & i + 1 & ","
                If Len(sRows) > 235 Then
                    UpdateFormats Left(sRows, Len(sRows) - 1), lCol
                    sRows = ""
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        If sRows <> "" Then UpdateFormats Left(sRows, Len(sRows) - 1), lCol
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Time taken: " & Format(Timer - dStart, "0.00s")
End Sub

Sub UpdateFormats(sRows As String, lCol As Long)
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        With Intersect(.Range(sRows), .Columns(lCol)).Offset(-1, 0)
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End With
        With .Range(sRows)
            .Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thnx Mate It Worked out